# How to keep resizing row height or readjust row height onFormSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Have this code in the Google Forms App Script to resize rows to a height of 65 and if there are more than 4 lines, autoResize. It seems to function properly until after a row with a single line gets to row 5, it will autoResize it.

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Q");
  var row = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var cell = sheet.getRange("M2");

  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}]);
 
  sheet.setRowHeight(2, 65);
  if(row > 4 || row > 4 || row > 4)
  {
     row.autoResizeRows(1, 1);
  } 

  row
     .setFontFamily("Arial")
     .setFontWeight("bold")
     .setFontSize(10)
     .setHorizontalAlignment("center")
     .setVerticalAlignment("middle");

  if(!cell.isBlank())
  {
    row
       .setFontColor('#FF0000')
       .setFontSize(12);
  }
}
```

Not really sure why it's doing that. In the Google Sheets' App Script, added this to check every row again and size accordingly. This doesn't seem to be functioning

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");     // SHEET NAME

function onFormSubmit(e)
{
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i=2;i<data.firstBlankRow;i++)
  {
    sheet.setRowHeight(i, 67);

    if(data[i][4] > 4 || data[i][6] > 4 || data[i][7] > 4)
    {
      data[i].autoResizeRows(i, 1);
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.setRowHeight(data[i],65);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a sample with how your data is formatted in your Google Sheet?  and include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the form responses tab is called "Form Responses"

1. Make a new tab called "Form Responses (Formatted)"
2. In cell A1 of that tab, put this: ={'Form Responses'!A:Z}
3. Now Adjust your row height or any cell formatting or whatever and it will hold for all the new entries that come in.

Comment: On the new sheet, can formatting rows be done to rows according to specified parameters? Like if column x !isBlank() format. Also, is there an easy way to check if data contains more than x lines without scanning data for x return characters

Comment: yes. that's called "conditional formatting"